# Problem with a login control event

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I want to have a check as soon as the user logs in whether he was banned or not.. But I have the following problem:

```
    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid i = (Guid)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey; //CurrentUser is null
    if (UsefulStaticMethods.CheckIfUserISbanned(i))
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/Banned.aspx");
    }
}
```

How do I get the current user as soon as he makes the login?

Answer (score 1):

Do it here:

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
```

or

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Login.Authenticate Event to find out is the user is banned or not.

Answer (score 1):

As Mantrork says your best bet is to override

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

At this point the Membership.GetUser() is going to be blank however, the user has not yet finished authentication. Instead you need to pull the username from your login control;

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    bool Authenticated = false;
    Authenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) &&

    if (Authenticated)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName);
        Guid i = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey; //CurrentUser is null
        if (UsefulStaticMethods.CheckIfUserISbanned(i))
        {
            Server.Transfer("~/Banned.aspx");
        }
    }

    e.Authenticated = Authenticated;
}
```

(Code is from the top of my head, so not ran through VS)

Answer (score 0):

Login.Authenticate return true if user is authenticated in web application

Answer (score 0):

If your Login1 is a standard asp:Login control you can use:

```
MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName);
```